# Can we use JavaScript FileSystemAPI from a Webworker?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

Can we use the JavaScript FileSystemAPI from a webworker?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem

In their documentation they have not mentioned anything but while using it its throwing window not defined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really...

There used to be a `self.webkitRequestFileSystemSync()` method accessible in Worker scopes, but it's been deprecated. And the FileSystem object you'd get from a drop event can't be serialized, and thus can't be posted to Worker from the main thread.

However, I suspect you don't really want to work with the FileSystem API, which is not really useful in web contexts, but instead you may want to prefer the [File System Access API](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/), which gives your page access to the user's file system (even though it's still only available in Chromium based browsers).

But to use this API from a Web Worker is not simple either.
To make the request to the File System Access API, we need to be handling an user-gesture.  Web Workers don't have access to the UI and thus they don't either have access to UI events ([yet](https://github.com/Kaiido/EventPort.js)).

**So we must make the request from the UI thread.**

However, contrary to FileSystem objects, FileSystemHandles are serializable and can be posted though `postMessage()`, so once you get the handle, you can post it to your worker and do your work from there.

*In UI thread*

```
btn.onclick = async (evt) => {
  const dirHandle = await showDirectoryPicker();
  worker.postMessage( dirHandle );
};
```

Then in the Worker thread you can receive that handle in the `MesageEvent.data`, and work with it as you'd do from the main thread.

Here is a [live demo](https://navigate-sub-directory-from-a-worker.glitch.me/), and its [source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/navigate-sub-directory-from-a-worker?path=script.js%3A5%3A2).

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, can we persist the dirHandle in browser storage like localStorage during page reload & use later?

Comment: I don't think so no, you'd have to request it again.

Comment: @PradeeptaKumarKhatoi [it appears that you can save handles for something like a "recent files" list](https://web.dev/file-system-access/#storing-file-handles-or-directory-handles-in-indexeddb), but you will have to re-request permissions to read/write the file.

Answer (score 0):

[Webworkers global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) name is `global`, not `window`.
And there is no FileSystem API

Comment: so we can't use from a worker? is there any workaround?

Comment: @PradeeptaKumarKhatoi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystemSync

Comment: The global object is called `self` in a Worker scope, but thanks to  `globalThis` we can have a context agnostic access to the global object. (`global` is node).